# System.BadImageFormatException, how to find the offending dll

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a WPF application which is now upgraded to 64 bit and it has many references. Is there a way to find the offending binary that is failing to load as it could be a 32bit DLL. It gives a file name which is just the main WPF application

Comment: Use the debugger, it displays DLL load notifications in the Output window.  Given the high likelihood that this is an unmanaged DLL, be sure to use Project > Properties > Debug, "Enable native code debugging" ticked.  You'll see the "Loaded" notification, immediately followed by "Unloaded", followed by the exception.

Comment: ProcMon from sysinternals could help too, check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: This app works is like a shell that host multiple wpf apps. In debug, it starts an external program (.exe in C:\Temp) which then shows the splash and the shell. when you click an item in the main menu(each menu item is an app) it then calls the 64 bit WPF host and then creates a host.host.  an application lib (dll) is essentially wrapped in an executable. The main dll is one that has been upgraded to 64 bit. Looking at the debug log in the output win, and the only dll that got loaded and immediately unloaded is the Serilog. Not sure if that is the offending one. I’ve to check the bitness of it

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a copy of [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Set a filter for your executable, then start your application.

Since it will probably terminate when it tries to load the DLL (or other PE file for that matter) of the wrong bitness, the last DLL access is likely the one which causes the problem. Use the "Jump to" feature to locate it on disk and check its bitness.